# Restoring local .git folder -- Uncommitted changes not showing?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I had to restore my .git directory from a local copy after I accidentally lost a bunch of uncommitted changes. Is there something I have to do to re-load my uncommitted changes, or (since they're not automatically showing after restoring the .git folder) are they lost?

Comment: They're lost. Uncommitted (assuming also unstaged) changes aren't tracked by git (by definition) and so will not be in your .git folder. Restoring from a backup is likely to be the best solution.

Comment: You lost the local `.git` directory and your local files with uncommitted changes? Did you restore your `.git` directory by using a backup or did you just clone it?